# Test for OpenSSL enabled fails

Tags: php, typo3, php-openssl

I am testing if openssl is enabled and returns keys. Though openssl is enabled it is not returing keys. When tried to install the TYPO3 the error message is appearing.

```
if (extension_loaded('openssl')) {
   $testKey = @openssl_pkey_new();   
   if (is_resource($testKey)) {
   } else {
      echo ' Please check the integration of the PHP OpenSSL extension and if it is installed correctly.';
   }    
}
```

Please help to continue installation. Thanks

Comment: You could always try adding a `;` after the echo line

Comment: Or turning on [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025)

Comment: Or looking at your PHP Error log once in a while

Comment: I missed semicolon while editing, corrected it

Comment: Are you sure that you looked in the correct `php.ini` file, there is normally more that 1. One for the web server and one for PHP CLI

Comment: If you are using the web server do a `phpinfo();` and check the output. If you are using PHP CLI do `php --ini` and check the output

Comment: FYI, `@` means "if there's an error, please don't tell me".

Comment: No error message is thrown . error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `openssl.cnf` file is not correctly configured or cannot be found. Please also check the [openssl manual](http://php.net/manual/de/openssl.installation.php).

Comment: I was getting "The ordinal error" because of incompatible version of php_openssl.dll file. And now I am able to install the typo3