# OpenSSL PHP extension not loaded despite uncommenting it in php.ini

Tags: php, windows, openssl, xampp, php-ini

I removed the (;) before extension=php_openssl.dll in the php.ini file. I verified that textension_dir = "ext" and I checked that openssl is already there.
When I ran "php -m" it showed me that openssl as one of the loaded modules but this test returns the error (extension_loaded = false)

```
 if (!extension_loaded('openssl')){
        Errors::$errors[] = array(
            'title' => "OpenSSL Extension not loaded",
            'message' => "Laravel requires OpenSSL PHP Extension"
        );}
```

in c:/windows there is no php.ini file

[image]

Comment: Are you editing the right `php.ini` there are normally 2 One used by Apache and the other by PHP CLI. I guess you are only editing the CLI version

Comment: Look that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906381/test-for-openssl-enabled-fails#comment76875428_44908531

Comment: Look at `c:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini`

Comment: php.ini file does not exist in C:\xampp\apache\bin for my case @RiggsFolly

Comment: I am fairly sure it should

Comment: Is there another one anywhere in the XAMPP folder structure

Comment: no there is not I only have one inside php folder besides php ini production and php ini developement